# Parent suddenly becomes null as3

Tags: actionscript-3

I just learned AS3 a few months ago, so sorry if this sounds so newbie to you.

Here's my problem. I went to use removeChild, but there was an error saying:
ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller.

So, I traced the parent, and it was "null". But when I tried to trace parent of every object I have, it came out alright. Then why does it suddenly become null? And randomly at that! Do you have any idea how to correct this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, I think you have a little mistake.

below code same error.

ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller.

It's your case?

```
var mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
addChild(mc);
var childMc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
mc.addChild(childMc);

//this line wrong.
stage.removeChild(childMc);
```

If you case, `stage.removeChild(childMc);` change to `mc.removeChild(childMc);`

[removeChild()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#removeChild%28%29) means Removes the specified child DisplayObject instance from the child list of the DisplayObjectContainer instance. as `parent.removeChild(child);`

`stage` is `childMc` parent of parent.

`mc` is `childMc` parent.

or this case?

```
var mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
addChild(mc);
var childMc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
mc.addChild(childMc);

stage.removeChild(mc);
while(mc.numChildren)
{
    mc.removeChildAt(0);
}
```

If you this case, mc is removed by this line `stage.removeChild(mc);`
trying to mc child removeChild. already mc removed, so occur error. child must be removed from most below.

change to

```
while(mc.numChildren)
{
    mc.removeChildAt(0);
}
stage.removeChild(mc);
```

If you want clearly answer. must attach a code.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I safeguard against Error #2025:

```
if ( container.contains( displayObject ) )
    container.removeChild( displayObject );
```

But in general, be sure to only remove DisplayObjects that you have previously added.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used addChild, anywhere before calling removeChild?

The child should should be on the display list of the parent from which you are calling removeChild.

The parent is always null as long as it's not on the stage.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the child with wild abandon without remembering what its parent happens to be, you can do this:

```
if( child.parent )  child.parent.removeChild( child );
```